# Flask url_for producing wrong URL

Tags: python, flask

The url_for generator in flask is not working for one of my views (it works for other views). The generator is giving `/user/?name=Joe` while I expect `/u/Joe`.

In the template I am trying to get the URL for the user page using: `{{ url_for('user', name = g.user.name ) }}`

This is the corresponding view function:

```
@app.route('/u/<name>')
@login_required
def user(name):
```

At first this was working but something changed. I have tried changing the view name and url with no luck.

Any thoughts? I am at a loss on this one...

The full app is available on GitHub: https://github.com/joehand/weight-and-more-tracker

**Edit**: The `@login_required` decorated is the one provided by Flask-login.

Additionally, removing the `<name>` variable does not solve the issue. The URL is then just `/user`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In api.py you are registering a view with the name 'user' that is probably conflicting with the method named 'user'.

Comment: This is most definitely the cause of the issue - Flask registers routes by default with the `__name__` of the function that is provided to it.  However, if two entries with the same `name` are provided, the last one provided wins.  [Flask-MongoRest](https://github.com/elasticsales/flask-mongorest/blob/master/flask_mongorest/__init__.py) uses `add_url_rule` to register itself with Flask - and it uses the `name` keyword argument to tell Flask what to register it under.  So the `user` function gets overwritten with the `user` MongoRest class.

Comment: Thank you!!! That fixed it. I will make sure to use more specific names for API routes.

Answer (score 0):

did you 'wrapped' your function in `login_required` decorator? In your case `name` is supplied into url as a query string, not a flask view-function argument - maybe flask does not have a grip of the argument specification of your decorated `user` view-function.

from the [docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/viewdecorators/#login-required-decorator):

> So let’s implement such a decorator. A decorator is a function that
>   returns a function. Pretty simple actually. The only thing you have to
>   keep in mind when implementing something like this is to update the
>   **name**, **module** and some other attributes of a function. This is often forgotten, but you don’t have to do that by hand, there is a
>   function for that that is used like a decorator (`functools.wraps()`).
>
> ```
> from functools import wraps
> from flask import g, request, redirect, url_for
>
> def login_required(f):
>     @wraps(f)
>     def decorated_function(*args, **kwargs):
>         if g.user is None:
>             return redirect(url_for('login', next=request.url))
>         return f(*args, **kwargs)
>     return decorated_function
> ```

Comment: The @login_required decorator is the one provided by Flask-Login extension. Removing the decorator does not solve anything.